# Issue on macOS High Sierra - how can I make the Chrome background black?

Tags: high-sierra, google-chrome

I have multiple Google user accounts. My primary one is has a white background in Chrome, but the secondary one has a black background. I much prefer the black background, but I cannot figure out how to apply it to my main Chrome profile. As you all know, dark mode for Mac was introduced in macOS Mojave. Unfortuantely due to the age of this Mac Mini, I am stuck on macOS High Sierra.

Troubleshooting steps I've tried:
- Checking all extensions (they are the same between the two Chrome profiles)
- Looking for some browser setting in Chrome to make the background dark (cannot find one as of yet)

Here you can see the two Chrome windows. The black layout is what I want for both:
[image]